# Do changes from unbounded to bounded storage need runtime migration?

Tags: runtime, runtime-upgrade

Currently across the substrate code base, there are a lot of PRs updating storage items to bounded forms, example: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11591/

I am wondering what is the behavior if say a we are changing storage of `Vec<T>` that has 11 items into a `BoundedVec<T, I>` that only allows ten items? Does `BoundedVec<T,I>` truncate the value leaving the last value inaccessible via the high level storage abstraction? Does there need to be a runtime migration for cases such as this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, if the bounds being introduced are all known to be respected, they don't.

`BoundedVec` encodes exactly the same as a normal `Vec` (namely based on [being derived](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/81c3d9e594668a32935a5eb7ce546912251aced6/frame/support/src/storage/bounded_vec.rs#L46)). TO go a bit deeper, the bound is encoded in the type, as an associated `Get` type, which only a compile-time matter.

That being said, if any of the values that already exist in storage violate the bound, then bound, then the `Decode` implementation of `BoundedVec` [fails](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/81c3d9e594668a32935a5eb7ce546912251aced6/frame/support/src/storage/bounded_vec.rs#L160), and the storage item cannot be accessed. In these cases, `None` or `Default::default()` are returned. For these values, a migration is needed.